# Check if all boolean values in an array is true?

Tags: c++, arrays

Let's say I have this boolean array:

```
bool something[4] = {false, false, false, false};
```

Now, is there any simple way to check if all the values in this array is true/false at once?

Instead of doing it like this:

```
if(something[0] == false && something[1] == false..)
dothis();
```

Comment: Use a loop. Like in the duplicate above.

Comment: This question should not have been close, it is more specific than the alternative.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use [`std::all_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of)

```
#include<algorithm>
...
if (std::all_of(
      std::begin(something), 
      std::end(something), 
      [](bool i)
            { 
              return i; // or return !i ;
            }
)) {
      std::cout << "All numbers are true\n";
}
```

Comment: @Salgar Yeah, they are. `bool` is an integral type -> it's a number.

Comment: I understand that, he edited his answer. It was strange before.

Comment: If I'm using the std namespace I don't have to type std:: before things like cout and such, right? Does that apply to this as well? Also, if someone would like to simply explain why not that many people are using namespace std I'd appreciate that. :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice

Comment: @Hummelmannen yes it does apply to this as well, and refer the link that Salgar commented above

Comment: @Hummelmannen Not many people use `using namespace std;` because it's evil.

Comment: It would be nice to remark that all_of is only defined from C++11 on...

Comment: Just wanted to add an approach with pointers: `std::all_of(something, &something[4], [](bool b) {return b;});`

Comment: Using `return i == something[0];` (instead of `return i;` or `return !i;`) will tell you if all values are equal; then, if that's true, checking `something[0]` will tell you if all values are true. This is a simple way to check both conditions without using two passes of the array

Answer (score 8):

You can do this by summing:

```
#include <numeric> 

int sum = std::accumulate(bool_array, bool_array + 4, 0);
if(sum == 4) /* all true */;
if(sum == 0) /* all false */;
```

This has the advantage of finding both conditions in one pass, unlike the solution with `all_of` which would require two.

Comment: What about any array with millions bools and first one as `false` and need to check all `true` ?
`std::all_of` just uses `std::find_if_not`

Comment: @P0W: I was assuming the question was to find _both_ conditions, not either condition

Comment: Still you should not need to go through the whole array for either of the conditions if the first two elements are true and false respectively..

Answer (score 6):

Use a for loop.

```
allTrue = true;
allFalse = true;
for(int i=0;i<something.size();i++){
    if(something[i]) //a value is true
        allFalse = false; //not all values in array are false
    else //a value is false
        allTrue = false; //not all values in array are true
}
```

My syntax might be a bit off (haven't used C++ in a while) but this is the general pseudocode.

Answer (score 6):

You could search for the first false flag:

```
bool something[n];
...

bool allTrue = (std::end(something) == std::find(std::begin(something),
                                                 std::end(something),
                                                 false) );
```

Comment: How does this add to the accepted answer from seven years ago?

Comment: @DevSolar it's a different approach.  Similar to std::all_of, but different nonetheless..  Plus it doesn't need a lambda.